# Calculate Multiple Distance Between Multiple Lat/Long in PHP Loop

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I have below two  `Driver_position` and `user_position` table where user and driver lat/long position are being updated. I Need to findout driver_id's for each user_id who are near to 5km of user_position , so that result will be like  `user_id1 = driver_id1,driver_id2,driver_id3 etc` For `user_id2=driver_id5`

[image]

So far I have below code to calculate distance in km. How can I achieve above in PHP

```
$lat1 = deg2rad($user_latitude);
        $lon1 = deg2rad($user_longitude);
        $lat2 = deg2rad($driver_latitude);
        $lon2 = deg2rad($driver_longitude);

        $latDelta = $lat1 - $lat2;
        $lonDelta = $lon1 - $lon2;

        $earthRadius=3959;

        $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
        cos($lat2) * cos($lat1) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));

        //return $angle * $earthRadius;  

        $dis= ($angle * $earthRadius)/0.62137; // miles to km conversion mi / 0.62137 = km
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below Mysql query for your solutions

```
// To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371

SELECT user_position.*,driver_position.driver_id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37.4219983) ) * cos( radians( driver_position.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( driver_position.longitude ) - radians(-122.0844) ) + sin( radians(37.4219983) ) * sin(radians(driver_position.latitude)) ) ) AS distance FROM user_position ,driver_position where user_position.user_id=10002 HAVING distance < 10000
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: You can direct run my given query into phpmyadmin or mysql for check.. It's working.

Comment: can i take the user_position.latitude as well instead of fixed value radians(37.4219983) i tried but not working in that way

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can pass dynamic value as per your requirements. check with your below given code

```
$pickup_latitude='37.4219983'; $pickup_longitude='-122.084'; 

$sql="(SELECT *,driver_location.driver_id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('".$pickup_latitude."') ) * cos( radians( driver_location.latitude ) ) * cos(radians( driver_location.longitude ) - radians('".$pickup_longitude."') ) + sin( radians('".$pickup_latitude."') ) * sin( radians( driver_location.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance FROM driver_location where driver_location.status='Online' HAVING distance >=0)"
```

you are passing $pickup_longitude variable value with single quotes so its consider value as '$pickup_longitude'. You need to pass its value with Double quotes like '".$pickup_longitude."'

Try above code.

Comment: Yes it works for a single $pickup_latitude and $pickup_longitude. how about if I try to compare each $pickup_latitude and $pickup_longitude available in user_position table with each lat/long in driver_position table, I mean every user with every driver